# Should I put user ID on taggings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following associations:

**models/tag.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :taggings
has_many :articles, through: :taggings
```

**models/article.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

**models/taggings.rb**

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :article
```

In my application I want to do 3 things with tags:

First, I want to be able to create an article and create new tags that belong to me.

Second, I want to be able to use other user's tags that they put on their articles.

Third, I want to be able to tag another user's article with the same tag so I can remember what I tagged it as.

To get to this point, do I have to put a `USER ID` on my `Tagging` model? What else do I have to do? Is this it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `user_id` on `taggings` you then have access to the `tag` and the `article` so yes, that's good. However if you explicitly want articles and tags that belong to you I would add `user_id` to article as well (in addition to the `user_id` you currently have on a `tag`).

To use other user's tags you can just call `article.tags` on any article to see what tags the article has.

To add a tag to another user's article is still available in this setup since the article has many tags, and there are no restrictions on who can add tags to an article, and regardless of the tags on an article the article will still belong to that other user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `User` to 'own' their `Tagging`s, then yes, you need a `user_id` on the `taggings` table.